# Java login - MS Access database

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I'm trying to create a Java Swing login form. My program has two `JTextFields` (Username and Password) and a `JButton` ("Submit"). I've connected this program with an MS Access database.

Here's the code I've written just to connect to the database:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\Libsoft\\Libsoft.accdb";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
 System.out.println("Connection Succesfull");
```

I'll use `usernamefield.getText()` to get the typed username and then I want to 
search that in the database. 
Once the program finds the typed username under the username column, I want to retrieve data from the adjacent cell i.e the cell under the password column. 
 I'll then check whether the typed password matches the one from from the database or not and if it does, I'll grant access to the user.

I'm a beginner and it's my first program that connects to a database. Please help me make it work according to the above mentioned process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what exactly does not work? What is the error/problem you have?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I don't know how to retrieve data from the adjacent cell. Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: If you "don't know how to retrieve data" then you have to learn it. Learn about SQL and work through Java tutorials dealing with database access. SO ist not a learning shortcut.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I read a lot about it. But nowhere did I find a way to retrieve data from the adjacent cell. Can you please help me find that way?

Answer (score 1):

> But nowhere did I find a way to retrieve data from the adjacent cell.

I don't know much about SQL but I doubt you would get data from an adjacent cell. You need to know the name of the column in the table.

You need to create a query using SQL. Assuming you have a table (UserTable) with two columns (UserId, Password), you might create a query like (untested code):

```
try
{
    String sql = "Select Password from UserTable where UserId = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString( 1, userName.getText() );
    stmt.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) // userid found, validate the password
    {
        String password = rs.getString(1);

        // test if password matches the value entered in the text field
    }
    else  // user not found
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid UserId");
    }
    stmt.close();
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The `PreparedStatment` is easy to use because it will format the SQL properly for you when using parameters.

For more information about SQL you need to read a text book or you can start with the Java tutorial on [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @camickr! I know the name of the column. Here's what I want to do : I want the program to find the username to find a match under the  `Username` column and then get data from its adjacent cell under the `Password` column.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke, I don't know why you keep taking about the "adjacent cell". That means nothing to me. That is not how a database works. I gave you an example query that will return the password for the userid. That is all the help I can offer.